# Dagger2 error: Cannot provide without @Inject constructor

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

i'm totally new to Dagger 2 and have a small problem. Hope you can help me :)
I have the following classes in my android project

1. App
2. AppComponent
3. AppModule
4. MainActivity
5. MainComponent
6. MainModule
7. IntentStarter

At rebuilding/compiling i get the error

```
Error:(15, 10) error: xyz.IntentStarter cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
xyz..MainActivity.intentStarter
[injected field of type: xyz..IntentStarter intentStarter]
```

I tried a lot of variants but without success... I tried it with a constructor in the IntentStarter class.. without constructor... :/
Now some code...

```
// AppComponent.class
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
// Empty...
}
```

...

```
// AppModule.class
@Singleton
@Module
public class AppModule {

    Application application;
    Context context;


    public AppModule(Application app) {
        this.application = app;
        this.context = app.getApplicationContext();
    }


    @Provides
    public Application provideApplication() {
        return application;
    }

    @Provides
    public Context provideContext() {
        return context;
    }

    @Provides
    public EventBus provideEventBus() {
        return EventBus.getDefault();
    }

    @Provides
    public IntentStarter provideIntentStarter() {
        return new IntentStarter();
    }
}
```

...

```
// App.class
public class App extends Application {

    public AppComponent appComponent;

    public AppComponent getAppComponent() {
        return appComponent;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .appModule(new AppModule(this))
            .build();
    }
}
```

...

```
//MainAcitivty.class
public class MainActivity extends MosbyActivity {

    @Inject
    IntentStarter intentStarter;

    MainActivityComponent component;

    @Override
    protected void injectDependencies() {
        component = DaggerMainActivityComponent.builder()
                .appComponent(((App) getApplication()).getAppComponent())
                .build();
        component.inject(this);
    }
}
```

...

```
//MainActivityComponent.class
@ActivityScope
@Component(dependencies = {AppComponent.class})
public interface MainActivityComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

...

```
// MainActivityModule
@Module
public class MainActivityModule {

}
```

...

```
//IntentStarter
public class IntentStarter {

    @Inject
    Context context;

}
```

Comment: Your provision methods are missing from AppComponent.

Comment: What do you mean? In my AppComponent i point to my AppModule and there is a provide method for the IntentStarter

Comment: I am not really into Dagger 2, but maybe this helps? http://siphon9.net/loune/2015/04/dagger-2-0-android-migration-tips/ (See below to find your error - try to add a `provideIntentStarter`-method to your component) Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry I had a dentist appointment and was busy getting my root filled (hence the short answer), but your subscope component cannot see the provided dependencies of AppComponent because you did not specify the stuff your appcomponent can publicly provide from its modules. When I get home and am not on a phone, I will write a full answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing first, as I said, your provision methods are missing from your components. For example,

```
 @Component(modules={AppModule.class})
 @Singleton
 public interface AppComponent {
        Context context();
        IntentStarter intentStarter();
 }

 @Component(dependencies={AppComponent.class}), modules={MainActivityModule.class})
 @ActivityScope
 public interface MainActivityComponent extends AppComponent {
        //other provision methods
 }
```

And you are making a mistake with field injection, your IntentStarter needs to either call `appComponent.inject(this)` or needs to get your context in a constructor parameter.

Also, I think the `@Provides` annotated method needs the `@Singleton` scope to get a scoped provider, and marking the module itself doesn't actually do anything.

So, to be specific,

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class})
    public interface AppComponent {
    Application application();
    Context provideContext();
    EventBus provideEventBus();
    IntentStarter provideIntentStarter();
}

@Module
public class AppModule {
    Application application;
    Context context;

    public AppModule(Application app) {
        this.application = app;
        this.context = app.getApplicationContext();
    }


    @Provides
    public Application provideApplication() {
        return application;
    }

    @Provides
    public Context provideContext() {
        return context;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public EventBus provideEventBus() {
        return EventBus.getDefault();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public IntentStarter provideIntentStarter(Context context) {
        return new IntentStarter(context);
    }
}

@ActivityScope
@Component(dependencies = {AppComponent.class}, modules={MainActivityModule.class})
public interface MainActivityComponent extends AppComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}

public class IntentStarter {    
    private Context context;

    public IntentStarter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }   
}
```